# How to monitor number of flows during draining?

Tags: corda

According to https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.0/key-concepts-node.html?highlight=drain#draining-mode

When I set the drainingMode to true. How do I monitor the number of in-flight flows according to the following : 
`As their number - which can be monitored through RPC - reaches zero, it is safe to shut the node down.`

Answer (score 0):

Having confirmed DrainingMode is activated using [this](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/is-flows-draining-mode-enabled.html)

You can then query the state machine either using stateMachinesFeed or stateMachinesSnapshot, details [here](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/state-machines-feed.html) and [here](https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.messaging/-corda-r-p-c-ops/state-machines-snapshot.html) respectively.

The stateMachinesSnapshot will return a list of StateMachineInfo, each representing a live flow. You can interrogate the StateMachineInfo for details on the flow including why it was started etc.

The stateMachinesFeed in addition also provides an observable of future state machine adds/removed. You could use this for additional monitoring.